C++ Meson как выбрать компилятор
Возможно ли в системе сборки Meson выбрать компилятор для C++? Например когда в системе установлен и clang и gcc и нужно дать приоритет clang без изменения вручную настроек системы, переменных среды и передачи вручную особых аргументов при сборке? Напрямую в meson.build файле как-то проверить установленные компиляторы и выбрать из списка нужный.
P.S. Если же никакими окольными путями такое невозможно, то например Cmake так умеет?
